# What does "result of a qualification" mean in the UK?

Tags: application, united-kingdom, degree

I am applying for a postdoctoral position in the UK and where I need to put my qualification, it is asked about the result. For example, when I fill in the details of my B.Sc. degree, what am I expected to put as result? I have no idea what that is supposed to mean. I have never seen it in my country or in any other application I filled out before. I mean, obviously it cannot be asking whether I got the degree or not, because that should be obvious by the fact that I am filling it in.

Answer (score 6):

British students are awarded an undergraduate degree with a grade, either first class honours (1st), upper second class honours (2.1), lower second class honours (2.2), third class honours (3rd) or pass without honours. This is what the form is asking for.

Almost all post graduate degrees have a minimum entrance requirement.  Often either a 2.1 or 2.2 or equivalent depending on the program and university.

While the 1st-3rd system is not internationally common, most university systems give some sort of grade (GPA out of 4 in the US for example, I've also seen GPA out of 20 from some middle Eastern counties). Universities have access to databases that term then what the grade system is in each county and how to convey it into a grade in the British system.

Note this applies to undergraduate and taught postgraduate degrees. PhDs are pass/fail and here is just write "pass".

Comment: Right, my country has something analogous to the GPA that is a number from 0 to 1. What they want is that number then?

Comment: The OP appears to be at the postdoctoral rather than PG stage, so possibly the references to "admissions tutors" might be a little misleading.

Comment: @YemonChoi you are right,  I missed that.  I've edited it to remove references to admissions tutors and added something about PhDs.

Comment: @user1620696 yes,  I'd just put that.  To be honest,  I don't really expect that anyone will pay much attention to your undergrad grade for a postdoctoral position,  but it's the same form used for all jobs.